# Unable to use .toChar() after readLine()

Tags: kotlin

I am Unable to use the `.toChar()` in Kotlin after the `readLine()!!`

Like in This Case

```
//An Array Of Characters
    var CharAr= Array<Char>(5){' '}
    for(i in 0..4){
        println("Please Enter The character Number ${i+1}")
        CharAr[i]= readLine()!!.toChar()
    }
```

Or Even In This Case

```
//Normal readLine()
var CharacterNum1:Char
    println("Please Enter a Character")
    CharacterNum1= readLine()!!.toChar()
```

Thank You For Your Help :)

Comment: I hope you do it in InteliJ and your auto-completion works :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readLine()` returns a `String?`. This type does not have a `toChar` method. What you can do is take the first char of that `String` like this:

```
charAr[i] = readLine()?.get(0) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
```